# How do I pass variables/data from a JS file to an HBS file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js

I am pulling database data in the 1st JS file, controller.js.

I need to pass it to the front-end file that's making use of the data to display it/graph it.

Call it, view.hbs

I tried:

controller.js:
data.exports={data};

view.hbs
const { data } = require('Project/views/controller.js')

But I get a "ReferenceError: require is not defined".

Not sure if there's an alternative way to pass data/variables.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in EJS (`<% ... %>`) on in an HTML `<script>` element that happens to be generated from EJS?

Comment: I'm trying to do this in an HTML <script> element. I'm actually not using EJS, rather I'm doing this in a .hbs (handlebars template) file.

Answer (score 0):

`require` is function that is available in node environment.

If you want to use it in browser you need to compile code using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) for example.